# Switch statement in thymeleaf doesn't work

Tags: html, switch-statement, thymeleaf

Im sending one parameter from controller. Parameter role. In html using thymeleaf when I print thath parameter with th:value I got value of that parameter. But when Im using th:switch it doesn't work. Here is code.

```
<input
        th:value="${role}"
        id="role"
        type="text"
>
```

print value "MANAGER" which I sent from controller

```
<th:block th:switch="${role}">
<ul th:case="MANAGER" class="list-unstyled components">
```

It doesn't work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think you need single quotes around MANAGER.

Comment: Why dont you use sec:authorize Spring Security features with thymeleaf. Here is an example https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-example/